# How to create IBM Cloud Event Streams trigger with terraform?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions, terraform-provider-ibm

I have an Event Streams instance called `myKafka` (with an appropriate topic called `myTopic`) and an IBM Cloud Function action called `myAction`. I want to trigger the `myAction` when a message arrived on `myKafka`'s topic. I have to write this relation in terrafrom. I have checked [this documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/function_trigger) but it only shows examples for alarm trigger and not based on Event Streams. So my question is how to create it with terrafom?

I am trying with the following:

```
resource "ibm_function_trigger" "myTrigger" {
  name      = "myTrigger"
  namespace = "myNameSpace"
  feed {
    name = "???"
      parameters = <<EOF
        [
          {
            "key":"???",
            "value":"???"
          },
          {
            "key":"???",
            "value":"???"
          }
        ]
      EOF
  }
}
```

I don't really know what should I put into the question marks' place. I expect the `myKafka` instance and `myTopic` should be passed with the `myAction` but could not determine the feed's name and keys with appropriate values.

Comment: You could define that trigger using the CLI or UI, then read it out using a TF data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally made it with this configuration:

```
resource "ibm_function_trigger" "myTrigger" {
  name      = "myTrigger"
  namespace = "myNameSpace"
  feed {
    name = "/whisk.system/messaging/messageHubFeed"
      parameters = <<EOF
        [
          {
            "key":"kafka_brokers_sasl",
            "value":<MY_KAFKA_BROKERS_SASL>
          },
          {
            "key":"user",
            "value":"<MY_USERNAME>"
          },
          {
            "key":"password",
            "value":"<MY_PASSWORD>"
          },
          {
            "key":"topic",
            "value":"myTopic"
          },
          {
            "key":"kafka_admin_url",
            "value":"<MY_KAFKA_ADMIN_URL>"
          }
        ]
      EOF
  }
}
```

The keys and `/whisk.system/messaging/messageHubFeed` are important.